# Permutations and Combinations reference request

Tags: reference-request, permutations, combinations

I have an exam on Wednesday on Permuations and Combinations and while I understand most of the concepts, I find it difficult to apply it to the questions because I haven't done many practice questions. I was wondering if someone had an excellent book on the topic that I could go through and understand permutations and combinations well.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean counting exercises?

Comment: @exitingcorpse I guess (?) What do you mean by "counting exercise"?

Comment: things like "if you're at a bakery that sells ten types of donuts, how many different dozen-packs of donuts can you buy"

Comment: @exitingcorpse Oh right, yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for, for both combinations and permuations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend *Probability and Statistics with Applications: A Problem-Solving Text* by Asimow/Maxwell, along with its solutions manual. (You can find a link to both of these books here: http://www.actexmadriver.com/Textbooks-and-Solutions-Manuals-C1636.aspx .) When I was studying for the actuarial exam covering probability, I struggled with combinations and permutations until I found this book, which gives a good buildup of difficulty of combination/permutation problems. The solutions are (mostly) very clear in how the approach to each problem works.

Good luck!

Comment: Is there any other books that you may know of? This book is difficult to order currently.

Comment: You could try *Probability for Risk Management* by Hassett/Stewart, but it's not as good.